# Applet 1.6 on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos

I have an applet that I am attempting to test in the 64-bit 1.6 Java VM on Mac OS X.  However, Safari is continuing to load the 1.5 VM.  I have tried changing the default applet VM to 1.6 in the Java Preferences with no effect.

Is there a way to use the new 1.6.0_13 applet VM in Safari (or other browsers) on the Mac at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

Since applets run inside the browser, in order to run the applet in 64-bit Java, you need to use a 64-bit browser.

Prior to Snow Leopard (10.6), Safari was 32-bit.

If you use a 64-bit browser, you should be able to use the 64-bit VM.